# how in python remove all folder inside path

Tags: python, operating-system, centos7

How can I list all folders of a directory in Python and remove them ?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/home/m110/public_html/ts/'):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

i run this code in Centos7 but i just need list folder for delete times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting folders in python recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118029/deleting-folders-in-python-recursively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

dirs= next(os.walk(r'/home/m110/public_html/ts/'))[1]
for name in dirs:
    print name
    shutil.rmtree(name)
```