# Deleting folder in python in the background

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

The standard way of deleting folders in python I am aware of is

```
 shutil.rmtree('/path/to/folder')
```

However, this command blocks until the deletion is completed, which in the case of large folders can take a long time.

Is there a non-blocking alternative? I.e. a function that would delete the folder in the 'background' but return immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most of the time spent is spent in system calls, a thread can help

```
import threading,shutil

threading.Thread(target = lambda : shutil.rmtree('/path/to/folder')).start()
```

that is the shortest way. Maybe a better way would be to create a proper function so the call can be wrapped in a try/except block. Alternatives here: [Deleting folders in python recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118029/deleting-folders-in-python-recursively)

Another alternative would be to call a system command like `rm` in the background but that is not very portable, even if this would be faster, but only slightly since most of the time is spent in the operating system anyway.

Comment: Would I do `os.system('rm -r /path/to/folder &')`? Do you know how the performance compares between `rm`and `shutil`?

Comment: I'd say rm would be _slightly_ faster. And also simpler to implement specially with `-f` option. shutil can choke on protected files if not properly configured. But running a system command to delete a file is really overkill and bad practice in python

Comment: thanks! well, you mention mostly advantages of `rf`. let's assume it would be guaranteed that the code is executed on a platform that provides `rf` - would you still consider its usage bad practice? if so, why?

Comment: if your script runs on unix/linux and will never be ported anywhere you can use a `rm` system call. I personally never assume that my scripts won't be ported.