# Delete all content in folder with Python

Tags: python

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python), I'm trying to delete the contents of a folder with this code

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('/YOUR/PATH/*')
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

But python returns an Attribution Error "'str' object has no attribute 'remove'". What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You would appear to be assigning a string to the variable `os`. You don't show that code however. Is this all your code?

Comment: `os` is not the variable here. And yes, that's all my code. Still no problem solved.

Comment: os.remove() takes a path as parameter. f is the file name here.

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback for the `AttributeError` exception.

Answer (score 11):

For deleting an entire directory, use `shutil.rmtree('/your/path')`

Read more from Python docs

Check out a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/303200/2041110) that has already been answered

Comment: This also deletes the enclosing folder, while I just want to delete the contents inside of it.

Comment: @RicardoDahis You can always recreate the empty directory once everything is removed. You dont have to loop through the individual files

Comment: Thanks Bob! I'm doing this inside a loop, like
`for folder in ['/folder1', '/folder2']:
       shutil.rmtree(path+folder)
       os.mkdir(path+folder)`
But `os.mkdir` returns "'str' object has no attribute 'mkdir'".

Comment: @RicardoDahis  You have corrupted your `os` import. You really do appear to have assigned a string to `os`. How about posting the full traceback?

Comment: Am suspecting that something is wrong with the path you are supplying. Try os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, folder))

Comment: Sorry Bob, that also doesn't work.

Comment: Here's the full traceback:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/--/run_directory.py", line 19, in <module>
    os.mkdir(path_build+folder)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mkdir'`

Comment: @RicardoDahis: you can try all the `os` functions you like, however, _none_ of them will work whilst `os` is a reference to a string, and not the actual module.

Comment: @mhawke, you are right! I was doing something really stupid here. Sorry for bothering and thank you all for the answers.

Comment: @RicardoDahis: thought so :) What was the problem?

Comment: I was defining a variable called `os` some lines above for other purposes =O

Answer (score 0):

As Bob Ezuba said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983351/21945), `shutil.rmtree()` is a better way to do it. You can recreate the directory if needed.

Using `glob.glob('/your/path/*')` will not find hidden files named with a leading `.`. You could call `glob()` multiple times, but that's getting ugly. Nor will `glob()` allow you to differentiate between files and directories, making it difficult to remove subdirectories. `shutil.rmtree()` will remove all files and subdirectories.

Alternatively you can rename the directory, recreate it anew, then `rmtree()` the old one. This might be better if you have any processes writing to files in the directory. And it won't leave your directory in a mess if `rmtree()` fails to remove some of the files, e.g. due to permissions.