# How to remove a lot of folders at once using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I have seen a lot of questions ([Delete Folder Contents in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python), [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-do-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python?lq=1), [How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty-with-python?rq=1)) asking how to delete a folder (empty or not) but I haven't seen any asking about how to delete a large number of folders at once.

I tried using `shutils` and writing something as `shutils.rmtree('.../run*')` (all the folders that I want to delete are called run0000, run0001 and so on) but this doesn't work because * is not understood.

I finally ended up importing subprocess and using `subprocess.Popen('rm -r ./run*/', shell=True)` which works because of the `shell=True` but I would like to avoid this due to the security related hazards that discourage the use of `shell=True`.

What is the best way to erase a large number of folders (non-empty) at once? I think that it must be to adapt some of the answers given in one of the linked questions but I haven't been able so far. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to locate the directories, then use `shutil.rmtree()` on each:

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil

for path in iglob('.../run*'):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Because you don't need to have a complete list of all matched directories, I used [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to yield matched paths one by one.