# How to delete a Parquet file on Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, parquet

I have saved a parquet file on Spark using `DataFrame.saveAsParquet()` command.

How can I delete/remove this file via python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This parquet "file" will actually be a directory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty-with-python) shows how to delete a directory with files in it

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/folder_name')
```

Comment: It works without the forward slash. 

shutil.rmtree('folder_name')

Comment: Note that this only works on the OS and is not applicable on HDFS, S3, or myriad other common locations for Parquet files being used in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Since @bsplosion mentioned *HDFS*, here is how you could do it in a pySpark-script:

```py
import subprocess

print("Deletion code:", subprocess.call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm", "-r", "-skipTrash", "hdfs:/your/data/path"]))

# hadoop     - calls hadoop
# fs         - calls hadoops file system implementation
# -rm        - calls the remove command
# -r         - recursive removal in order to remove the entire directory
# -skipTrash - As it states: Skip the trash and directly remove everything
```

This returns *Delection code: 0* if executed successfully, otherwise *Delection code: -1*.
You can read more about hadoops `-rm` [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#rm) in the docs.