# Delete file start with

Tags: python

I want this function to delete files.  It does this correctly, but it *also* deletes folders, which I do not want.

I also get an error during execution:

```
Access is denied: 'C:/temp3\\IDB_KKK
```

In folder temp3 i have:

```
IDB_OPP.txt
IDB_KKK - folder
```

Code:

```
def delete_Files_StartWith(Path,Start_With_Key):
    my_dir = Path
    for fname in os.listdir(my_dir):
        if fname.startswith(Start_With_Key):
            os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, fname))

delete_Files_StartWith("C:/temp3","IDB_")
```

Comment: Shortened wording, fixed sentence structure, improved code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following, to check if it is a directory:

```
os.path.isdir(fname) //if is a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a directory and all its contents, [use `shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

> The shutil module offers a number of high-level operations on files and collections of files.

Refer to the question [How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/303225/137650)

```
import shutil

..
    if fname.startswith(Start_With_Key):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(my_dir, fname))
```

Comment: This may be what the OP wants (given a broad enough interpretation of the trainwreck v.1 text of the question), *or* it may be the opposite of what the OP wants (delete files but *not* folders, as in the interpretation Prune took for the v.2 edit)

Comment: Agreed. If that's the case, the isdir() check is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete files recursively (i.e. including files that live in *subdirectories* of `Path`) without deleting those subdirectories themselves?

```
import os
def delete_Files_StartWith(Path, Start_With_Key):
    for dirPath, subDirs, fileNames in os.walk(Path):
        for fileName in fileNames: # only considers files, not directories
            if fileName.startswith(Start_With_Key):
                os.remove(os.path.join(dirPath, fileName))
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by the following:

```
def delete_Files_StartWith(Path,Start_With_Key):
    os.chdir(Path)
    for fname in os.listdir("."):
        if os.path.isfile(fname) and fname.startswith(Start_With_Key):
            os.remove(fname)
```

thanks you all.