# How to remove a directory including all its files in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on some Python code. I want to remove the `new_folder` including all its files at the end of program.

Can someone please guide me how I can do that? I have seen different commands like os.rmdir but it only removes the path. Here is my code:

```
for files in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
  os.system("mv "+path+" new_folder")`
```

The code above will move a folder (called check) into new_folder. I want to remove that check folder from the new_folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty-with-python)

Answer (score 99):

If you want to delete the file

```
import os
os.remove("path_to_file")
```

but you can`t delete directory by using above code if you want to remove directory then use this

```
import os
os.rmdir("path_to_dir")
```

from above command, you can delete a directory if it's empty if it's not empty then you can use shutil module

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("path_to_dir")
```

All above method are Python way and if you know about your operating system that this method depends on OS all above method is not dependent

```
import os
os.system("rm -rf _path_to_dir")
```

Comment: Oh well here is how you this thing:... but actually this is how you do this thing: ... but REALLY this is what you asked for:...

Answer (score 35):

Just use [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my Approach:

```
# function that deletes all files and then folder

import glob, os

def del_folder(dir_name):
    
    dir_path = os.getcwd() +  "\{}".format(dir_name)
    try:
        os.rmdir(dir_path)  # remove the folder
    except:
        print("OSError")   # couldn't remove the folder because we have files inside it
    finally:
        # now iterate through files in that folder and delete them one by one and delete the folder at the end
        try:
            for filepath in os.listdir(dir_path):
                os.remove(dir_path +  "\{}".format(filepath))
            os.rmdir(dir_path)
            print("folder is deleted")
        except:
            print("folder is not there")
```

Comment: Can anyone comment on this method? I see negative votes but I do not fundamentally disagree with what is written above

Answer (score -5):

use `os.system("rm -rf" + whatever_path +" new_folder")`

Comment: But I want to remove a folder that is inside another folder.

Comment: I want to use something like. If os.path.exists() then remove

Comment: the use os.system("rm -rf " + path + "/new_folder"). Also, the -f function does not throw an error if the folder does not exist so you are already set

Comment: Better to use `shutil.rmtree` suggested in other answers. This answer opens up the possibility of arbitrary shell commands execution if the string `whatever_path` comes from untrusted input.