Deleting files on remote server via python script indicated as hidden
I have a Python script that initiates deletion of files in a folder on a remote SFTP server.
The deletion is indicated in the log.
Upon check on the remote directory and when I list with ls I get empty line and no files present:
sftp> cd PATH/
sftp> ls
sftp>

However when I list with ls -al:
sftp> ls -al
drwxrwxr-x    2 6055     6052         4096 Nov 20 05:23 .
drwxrwxr-x    4 6055     6052         4096 Oct 24 11:07 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         6742 Nov 15 20:10 .file1.csv
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         6742 Nov 18 19:23 .file2.csv
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         6743 Nov 19 19:21 .file3.csv
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         7179 Nov 15 18:52 .file4.csv
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         7178 Nov 18 18:03 .file5.csv
-rw-r--r--    1 6055     6052         7182 Nov 19 18:03 .file6.csv

The files listed using ls -al all begin with a . (dot), indicating that they are hidden files. The default ls command in SFTP does not show hidden files. Does it mean that I need to modify the script to include hidden files in the deletion process? Or are they indeed deleted /masked as deleted and won't be copied/transferred from other scripts?

Python behaves differently when operating on hidden files, as it goes against the operating system's wishes (to hide these files and protect them from user interference).
That being said, there are lots of examples of this type of problem on Stack Exchange:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804607/deleting-hidden-directories
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197463/how-to-search-for-a-folder-name-in-python-and-delete-it
Without seeing the Python code, it's hard to say what's going wrong, but the files are not being deleted. It could be several issues, even permissions.

show your code pls, we can't guess what you're doing.
