# What is the best method to tell a function in a tkinter GUI to wait until a system call made by shutils resolves before proceeding?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, system-calls, race-condition, shutil

I have a tkinter GUI that at some point prompts the user for a folder, checks if it exists, and then, if it does and the user consents, deletes and recreates it. I am doing this via the following code:

```
try:
   self.status_string.set('Cleaning up output directory to be overwritten')
   shutil.rmtree(output_folder)
   while os.path.exists(output_folder):
       time.sleep(1)
    os.makedirs(output_folder + '/events')
except OSError:
    self.status_string.set('Failed to create directory {0}, verify that you have permission to do so'.format(output_folder + '/events'))
```

I am currently calling `time.sleep` in order to force it to wait until the directory has been completely removed before trying to recreate it, because the contents can be large and it may take a while and I want to avoid the race condition. But it seems wrong to me to be using `sleep` during the `mainloop` of `tkinter`, and I am not certain that checking for existence after calling `rmtree` is valid. It seems to work in testing, but that could be luck. What is the proper way to wait for the system call to resolve before proceeding?

Comment: ***wait until the directory has been completely removed***: Why do you think the function returns before it completes? This is a long running task which will block the`tkinter` mainloop.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the answer in another question, then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty/43914402#43914402 suggests there are potential race conditions, which I assumed was due to the system call not blocking. Is that inaccurate?

Comment: ***there are potential race conditions***: The function can raise **OSError**, e.g. due to permissions.

Comment: Ah, so it needs its own try/ except block