# Clear a folder using python

Tags: python, file, delete-file

I want to clean a folder filled with files without deleting the folder and I cant for the hecc of it figure it our or find some documentation on the matter. (clearing the Temp folder filled with junk files and folders)

```
import os

os.remove(r"C:\Users\junio\AppData\Local\Temp\")
```

any suggestions to make it work? (probably pretty easy, and thanks in advance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove/delete a folder that is not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303200/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-folder-that-is-not-empty)

Comment: you have get all files and subfolder and delete elements one-by-one. OR delete this folder and later create it again.

Comment: You can also try this which is as far as I know windows only but should work: `os.system('rmdir /s /q "%temp%"')` obviously You can format the string and add other directories, this is just the shortest way to get to Temp

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import os, shutil
    folder = '/path/to/folder'
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to delete %s. Reason: %s' % (file_path, e))
```

Taken from [How to delete the contents of a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder)